# PromiseKit w/ URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession, promisekit

I am trying to add a check against the response status code in the event my remote service returns a `401`.

I have am trying to use the PromiseKit `URLSession` extension.

Imagine I have something basic such as

```swift
        return firstly {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: request)
        }.compactMap {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: $0.data)
        }
```

What I would like to do is add a check against the response state code, so I may throw an error and execute some further steps.

Something like

```swift
        return firstly {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: request)
        }.map { session  in
            if (session.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 401 {
                // throw a custom error here
                // something like
                // throw TokenProviderError.unauthorized
            }

            return session.data

        }.compactMap {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: $0)
        }.catch { error in
            // check the error thrown here and do something
        }
```

This has an exception

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'PMKFinalizer' to return type
>   'Promise'

Is it possible to introduce something like `retryWhen` which will allow me to catch an errors and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `.catch` doesn't return anything but you want to return a `Promise<T>` so you have to remove `.catch` here as,

```
return firstly {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: request)
}.map { session  in
    if (session.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 401 {
        // throw a custom error here
        // something like
        // throw TokenProviderError.unauthorized
    }

    return session.data

}.compactMap {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: $0)
}
```

`.catch` will be implemented by the callee.

---

OR, may be you are looking something like,

```
func test() -> Promise<Any> {
    return firstly(execute: { () -> Promise<String> in
        return .value("bhai")
    }).map({ string -> Promise<Double?> in
        return .value(0.1)
    }).compactMap({ double -> NSError in
        return NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve exactly the same thing as you did, I think the `retrywhen` feature you were looking for is called `recover`, you can find it in GitHub [PromiseKit Document](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md#recovery)

- **Please note the following code did not go through the editor, may not compile, I'm only using this to demonstrate the flow.**

```
return firstly {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: request)
        }.map { session  in
            if (session.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 401 {
                throw TokenProviderError.unauthorized
            }
            return session.data
        }.compactMap {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: $0)
        }
        // above is a copy of your code
        .recover { error in // instead of .catch, use .recover here
            guard let err = error as? TokenProviderError,
                  err == .unauthorized 
                  else { throw error } // we only care 401 error here, other error will be handled in caller's .catch

            // in my case, the reason for 401 error is due to an expired access token, so I will try to use refresh token to get a valid access token and make the same request again
            return firstly {
                loginWithRefreshToken(token: myRefreshToken)
            }.then { loginRes -> Promise<(data: Data, response: URLResponse)> in
                // loginRes contains new access token, set it to request "Authorization" header, and make the same request again
                request.setValue(loginRes.accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                return URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: request)
            }.map { session -> Data in
                return session.data
            }.compactMap { data -> Promise<T> in
                try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            }
        }
```

Maybe it's a bit late for the answer, but I hope it can help some coders who are new to PromiseKit like myself.